# Can't figure out why my program is not creating a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, range

I need to compare each number in a list back to back, subtract, and add the outcome to a new list.
so

```
list1[1]-[0] = list2 [0]
list1[2]-[1] = list2 [1]
```

etc.

But I can't get it to do this.
Here is my block

```
change = []
index = 0
popyear_up = 1
popyear_low = 0
while index < len(data_numbers):
#for i in range, len(data_numbers:
    difference = data_numbers[popyear_up] - data_numbers[popyear_low]
    change.append(difference)
    popyear_up += 1
    popyear_low += 1
    index += 1
```

The uncommented "while" line right now returns

```
difference = data_numbers[popyear_up] - data_numbers[popyear_low]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The commented line only does [1]-[0] and [2]-[1], but does them correctly and appends them to change[]

I have no idea why it only does those 2. But for the first one I feel it has something to do with the length of my main list of data and the length of the list I'm asking it to create.

So two different issues, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.

Full code if necessary

```
file = input('File to open: ')
infile = open(file, 'r')
source_file = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
index = 0
while index < len(source_file):
    source_file[index] = source_file[index].rstrip('\n')
    index += 1

data_numbers = [int(i) for i in source_file]


change = []
index = 0
popyear_up = 1
popyear_low = 0
while index < len(data_numbers):
#for i in range, len(data_numbers:
    difference = data_numbers[popyear_up] - data_numbers[popyear_low]
    change.append(difference)
    popyear_up += 1
    popyear_low += 1
    index += 1

#start_year = 1950
#change_sum =  float(sum(change))
#change_average = change_sum / len(change)
#max_change = start_year + change.index(max(n)) + 1
#min _change = start_year + change.index(min(n)) + 1

#print('Average Change in Population:',change_average)
#print ('Year with most population increas:',max_change)
#print ('Year with lease population increas:',min_change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists are of the same length and one of the indices (`popyear_up`) is one ahead, it will break. Instead, only go up to `index < len(data_numbers) - 1`.

Also, just do this:

```
change = []
popyear_up = 1
popyear_low = 0
for popyear_low in range(len(data_numbers) - 1):
    difference = data_numbers[popyear_low + 1] - data_numbers[popyear_low]
    change.append(difference)
```

Also, just do this:

```
change = [data_numbers[i + 1] - data_numbers[i] for i in range(len(data_numbers) - 1)]
```

Or if you want (though this is slightly less readable):

```
change = [y - x for x, y in zip(data_numbers, data_numbers[1:])]
```